# The Gilead Bomb by David Sinclair — Names of Alien Species

Tags: childrens-novel

Does anyone have a copy of [*The Gilead Bomb* by David Sinclair](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13487088-the-gilead-bomb)?  If so, can you do me a solid and look up the names of the alien species mentioned?  (There's no ebook version available.)  I have an ancient memory that I'm looking to confirm.  Please reply with the data spoiler-protected if possible.

If my memory is correct then it may lead to a further, more interesting conversation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Rinn are an evil alien species from another galaxy.

> The Narn are a good federation of seventeen hundred peaceful planets near the Crab Nebula.

(Paraphrased from THE GILEAD BOMB, pages 77-78)

Comment: Muchos danke!  I had the names Narn and Rim in my head and was uncertain about both.

Answer (score 0):

The enemy alien was the Rim (or possibly the Rimm; my copy of the book is at home).
Ace Astro's dog, who he'd named Sirius, was actually a Narn.

Comment: This just replicates the existing answer, but with less useful info